# React Caching Component between Rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I have a use case that I can't wrap my head around how to solve. Let's say I have a component called `Viewer` that has an iframe being rendered.

```
render() {
    return <iframe src={props.url}>Some Content Loaded</iframe>
```

The parent component loads 3 of the `Viewer` components, each with a different url for each

```
render() {
    <div>
        <Viewer url="https://example1.com"/>
        <Viewer url="https://example2.com"/>
        <Viewer url="https://example3.com"/>
    </div>
}
```

Now if I want to change the position of the 3 `Viewer` components, so an event would occur that would reload and change the order of the urls to "example3.com", "example1.com", "example2.com". I don't want to have to rerender `Viewer` and have a network call to each of the "example" endpoints. I would like to cache the component using a key, and check on url change, if it exists, and just use that.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be helpful

Comment: Could you use flexbox and just changing the `order` of the elements so that you're not really rerendering (in a react sense) but reorganizing the dom via css?